# Add flag as a label in the keyboard layout switcher, for layouts that do not have flags stored

Tags: kde, keyboard-layout

In KDE I would like to add the EU flag to the layout switcher for the EurKey layout:

[image]

Is this possible (without recompiling anything)?

P.S.: The above is on Kubuntu 18.04, but I am quite sure that a solution would be the same on all currently supported versions of Kubuntu.

Comment: Do you have a ~/.icons.flags folder?

Comment: @Mitch No, there is no such folder

Comment: Edit the label and set a [flag emoji](https://getemoji.com/#flags) instead of alphabetical letters? 

Comment: @pomsky How do I edit the label?

Comment: @pomsky Interesting, i can edit the text...now, how do I add emojis?

Comment: @pomsky The font used to display the labels does not support emojis, so after copy-paste it shows a square with a question mark. But, it was a nice shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy your flag (flag.png) in the following directory.

```
/usr/share/kf5/locale/countries/eu/
```

Τhe eu subdirectory has to be created. You do not need to create a complete locale file.

the result looks like this:

[image]

Checked on KUbuntu 18.04 to 19.10.

Comment: Does it need restart?

Comment: @Siadbakr. The file has to be named flag.png and you have to log out - log in. Just checked it on another computer too.

Comment: The Arabic character map that I have is named `ara` in Keyboard system settings module. I have created directory named `ara` in the specified path in which all directories are two characters names. I still have no flag.png image when switching two arabic.

Comment: @SaidbakR I copied my ./eu folder as ./ara and indeed it did not work. I guess there is also a 2 letter short-form for arabic, though I am unforunately not aware of it.

Comment: God bless Argentina!

Comment: @SaidbakR did you try with just `ar`? if it didn't work, that's probably because of name code conflict with Armenia character :/

Comment: @Bruni do you know which language code that keyboard layout use? Because Greek language isn't refered as `gr` but `el` according to [ISO 2 Letter Language Code](https://www.sitepoint.com/iso-2-letter-language-codes/)

Comment: @damadam It is the classic Greek layout. I think KDE does not use ISO 2 Letter Language Codes (the same reason arabic is not ar) and ar is Argentina. Also note that KDE needs codes for locales and not languages and there are more locales than languages

Comment: @Bruni it don't take care of `/etc/locale.gen` file too, using `cat /etc/locale.gen | grep gr` just give that result : `# agr_PE UTF-8`

Comment: @damadam Originally there is ar directory but it dedicated for Argentina, additionally as I regarded above, the character map name is **ara**.

Comment: @damadam my locale is : el_GR.UTF-8 UTF-8

Comment: @SaidbakR try to use the 2 uppercase letters code as shown by Bruni in this [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035279/add-flag-as-a-label-in-the-keyboard-layout-switcher-for-layouts-that-do-not-hav/1057873?noredirect=1#comment1991120_1057873), it's possible that KDE use these letters